# Can't Display image in a webpage laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4

I have a image in the `public/images` folder.I want to show this image in my webpage and I am trying like this

```
{{ HTML::image('public/images/20140208-IMG_2538.jpg') }}
```

But I cant see my image on my webpage.Instead It shows a broken image icon.What can i do can anyone suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `HTML::image()` expects a path that is relative to `public`. Try this:

```
{{ HTML::image('images/20140208-IMG_2538.jpg') }}
```